# Keycloak: Create User in a certain real which name is ExpRealm

Tags: keycloak

I am new in Keycloak, so my question is maybe little dummy. So the question is, can I create user in a realm (ie: ExpRealm) via API? If yes, how?

I tried that and...

```
curl --data "client_id"="admin-cli" --data "username"="admin" --data "password"="admin" --data "grant_type"="password" --request POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token

curl --header "Authorization: Bearer token" --request POST --data "username"="someone" http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/ExpRealm/users -vv
```

and I got that:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)

> POST /auth/admin/EDL/users HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer token
> Content-Length: 15
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 15 out of 15 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 03 May 2019 07:49:28 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a user by using the keycloak admin REST APIs.
Here's the spec for it -
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource

So in your case, the endpoint will become like this -
POST /auth/admin/ExpRealm/users

Body should be the user json 
[image: Payload]

Before you trigger this, get the access token and pass it in the header as Bearer token.

[image: Authentication Header]

Comment: maybe I used it wrong. but that is my logic:

I get token:
`curl --data "client_id"="admin-cli" --data "username"="admin" --data "password"="admin" --data "grant_type"="password" --request POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`

and I used after that, I want to create a new user:
`url --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer someting-token" --request POST --data "username"="valami" http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/ExpRealm/users -vv`

and after I got that:
...
404 Not Found
....

Comment: First of all did you created the ExpRealm realm in keycloak. Also I can see that the payload you are passing is wrong. I am sharing the curl that worked for me, Step 1 : curl --data "username=keycloak&password=keycloak&grant_type=password&client_id=admin-cli" http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token.... Step 2 : curl -v http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/ExpRealm/users -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN"   --data '{"firstName":"xyz","lastName":"xyz", "email":"demo2@gmail.com", "username": "demo2@gmail.com", "enabled":"true"}'